# Solve equation in number theory

Tags: number-theory

Let a belongs to the set Q\ S= { -1, 0, 1}. How do solve the equation below over S?

```
x*a^(1/x) + a^x/x == 2a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) with the added condition on `a`. Two ways to add this condition are:

```
a^2 <= 1
{a} ∈ Point[{{-1},{0},{1}}]
```

For example:

```
Reduce[x*a^(1/x)+a^x/x == 2a && a^2<=1, {a,x}, Integers]
```

> (a == -1 && x == 1) || (a == 1 && x == 1) || (x ∈ Integers && 
>      a == 0 && x >= 1)

or:

```
Reduce[x*a^(1/x)+a^x/x == 2a && {a} ∈ Point[{{-1},{0},{1}}], {a,x}, Integers]
```

> (a == 1 && x == 1) || (x ∈ Integers && a == 0 && 
>      x >= 1) || (a == -1 && x == 1)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = x*a^(1/x) + a^x/x == 2 a;

sol = Table[{aa -> a, Reduce[eqn, x, Reals] /. Equal -> Rule}, 
  {a, -1, 1}] /. aa -> a

(* {{a -> -1, x -> 1}, {a -> 0, x > 0}, {a -> 1, x -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. However, how can solve it theoretically please

Comment: @john that is a valuable stipulation that you should include in your question. If you’d like, I can edit & update it for you, if you are unable!

Comment: @CA Trevillian. I want to know the theoretical solution of the equation over the set of rational number \ {-1,0,1}.